# Going to gym after cycling for 20 kms

Tags: gym, bicycling

Today I went cycling around Tokyo for 20 kilometres. Sometimes the roads were straight, sometimes I had to sharply climb, and sometimes I was lucky enough to just leave the bike itself and it was going down to the road.

On Wednesday evenings I go to the gym. Do you think that my cycling experience is and adequate excuse for skipping gym today? I feel tired, but I do not want to cheat myself.

What would be the opinion of the fitness experts?

Comment: What do you do at the gym? If you wanted to lift heavy weights, a different answer would be appropriate than for the case that you planned to sit there on a stationary bike for an hour.

Comment: I personally think it depends how you feel and how long the cardio lasted. Moderate 30 minute to an hour cardio is fine on gym days. If you're doing cardio that lasts longer than that and you feel tired your workout will only make your body worse by causing a surge of cortisol, slowing down recovery and muscle gain, and fatiguing you. Walking a couple hours is fine but cycling that much is rough on the body

Answer (score 1):

You will have an awful day regardless of your choices if you let the gym condition you.

Choice 1) go to the gym and feel bad because you are not able to train with the intensity you are used to, and think all the time that you are just wasting time and you could just went home and relaxed.

Choice 2) go home and relax, you will feel as if you lied to yourself to make up an excuse to not train.

The only way to not feel bad about it is to decide what do you train for? Is it for pleasure or for an objective?

If your objective is to be healthier then just train the reccomended amount by your doctor, if you train for fun then just do it when you want to do and not when you feel forced to.